# Ignoring the "You must change your password within 60 minutes" pop-up

Tags: iphone, password

This morning I got the

> Passcode Requirement
>   You must change your iPhone unlock passcode within 60 minutes.

popup [covered in this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/124771/1514) (although none of the reasons there ring true). I decided it was safest to go ahead and change my password through the system menu just-in-case.

But if I had ignored it and let the 60 minutes run out, what would have happened?

- Would the device have wiped itself?
- Or modally force me to change the password before it'll let me use it again?
- Or put itself into a locked state that could only be recovered by my Exchange administrator?

or something else?

Thanks. I've skimmed threads on Reddit etc. about this and no one seems to have actually called its bluff, or at least they didn't report back if they did. This is my own phone attached to my work email account; there's no MDM profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ignored it many times and true to its word, it modally forces you to change the password.  You can lock/sleep the device, but if you want to do anything useful, you have to change the password first.

Answer (score 0):

I called Apple and was told that this isn't malware, that my phone must have received a message from one of my email accounts.  This doesn't make sense but I suggest that for further detailed information call Apple support and ask.